# Transfer Named Table in Workbook to Another File Master Worksheet and Copy Data into single Table

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA so hopefully I explain this clearly...

I will eventually have 32 different logs that have a table named "DriverLog".  They will all be saved in MyDocuments!!!Transportation_Issues_Log!!! as macro enabled files and then a single file in the same folder named "MasterDriverLog".  What I need is a macrobutton that will on each of the 32 documents update the "MasterDriverLog" file with new data.  Column D, or index 3 (Table starts on column B), is an incident number that will be unique for each document.  The idea is after the export, it deletes duplicates which makes for only exports of new driver incidents.

I've tried some code, but the one I have from somewhere else only uses ranges rows and columns.  It does pretty much the same idea, but will not delete duplicates.  I also realize that you must have both documents open... that is not a problem and I know the macro to make that happen.

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()


'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks(sPS).Worksheets(1)
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("MasterDriverLog.xlsm").Worksheets(1)

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

  'Optional - Select the destination sheet
  wsDest.Activate
```

By the way, the copy workbook object I am referring to is calling the module code for saving the file (which is where the macro is located):

```
Sub SaveBook()
'----------------------------------------------------
'Save File to Hard Drive
'----------------------------------------------------

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sPS As String

    sPS = Application.PathSeparator
    sPath = Environ("UserProfile") & sPS & "Documents" & sPS & "!!!Transportation_Issues_Log!!!" & sPS
    CreateDirectory sPath
    If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Couldn't create the path due to invalid or inaccessible location
    sFile = Range("G2").Value & "_DriverLog" & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & sFile, FileFormat:=52

    MsgBox ("This has been saved as '") & sPath & sFile & ("' in your documents folder.  You may create a shortcut, but please do not move target location of file.")

End Sub

Sub CreateDirectory(ByVal arg_sFolderpath As String)

    If Len(Dir(arg_sFolderpath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        Dim sPS As String
        sPS = Application.PathSeparator

        Dim sBuildPath As String
        Dim vFolder As Variant
        For Each vFolder In Split(arg_sFolderpath, sPS)
            If Len(vFolder) > 0 Then
                If Len(sBuildPath) = 0 Then sBuildPath = vFolder Else sBuildPath = sBuildPath & sPS & vFolder
                If Len(Dir(sBuildPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    MkDir sBuildPath
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Len(Dir(sBuildPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                        MsgBox "[" & sBuildPath & "] is either invalid or unreachable.", , "Create Directory Error"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next vFolder
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates).

Comment: What if that range is a table name?

Comment: Or could I do a range with just the column... the only thing I am really looking at for duplicates is the column with the incident numbers.  If there is a duplicate there, then that row could be deleted.  That is good to know, though, as well.